# Pandas Multiindex from array => TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to create the dataframe from the array with following structure:

```
df = [[{'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
        'name': 'Tom',
        'value': '129'},
       {'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
        'name': 'Kate',
        'value': '0'},
       {'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
        'name': 'GroupeId',
        'value': '0'}, {...}, {...}, {...}],[another list of dictionaries like the first one],[and another one]]
```

using this code:

```
def create_from_arr():
    baby_array=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df, names=['sessions', 'behaves'])
    return baby_array
```

I have the following error, that I couldn't understand:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

My desired output is like:

```
list 
                   date_time      name value
 1    0 2015-05-22 05:37:59       Tom   129
      1 2015-05-22 05:37:59      Kate     0
      2 2015-05-22 05:37:59  GroupeId     0
 2    3 2015-05-26 05:56:59     Hence   129
      4 2015-05-26 05:56:59      Kate     0
      5 2015-05-26 05:56:59     Julie     0
 3    ......................    ......  ......
```

Comment: what's your **df** exactly? There a few NameError which you don't have the minimal working code.... it's hard for others trying to help

Comment: sorry, my ```df``` is this array

Comment: your df is a multi-level array, so you need to flatten it to have your values properly stored in df, otherwise they are just {...}, {...} in your fields

Comment: What MultiIndex you want to extract exactly??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still not sure what exactly you want to do with the MultiIndex, but here is one way to "flatten" your dictionary in your multi-level arrays and load your data into the dataframe properly:

**Updated with "list" and "index" as MultiIndex**

```
In [100]: data = [[{'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
   .....:         'name': 'Tom',
   .....:         'value': '129'},
   .....:        {'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
   .....:         'name': 'Kate',
   .....:         'value': '0'},
   .....:        {'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
   .....:         'name': 'GroupeId',
   .....:         'value': '0'}], [{'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
   .....:         'name': 'Tom',
   .....:         'value': '129'},
   .....:        {'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
   .....:         'name': 'Kate',
   .....:         'value': '0'},
   .....:        {'date_time': Timestamp('2015-05-22 05:37:59'),
   .....:         'name': 'GroupeId',
   .....:         'value': '0'}]]

In [101]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['list', 'date_time', 'name', 'value'])

In [102]: for idx, each in enumerate(data, 1):
   .....:     temp = pd.DataFrame(each)
   .....:     temp['list'] = idx  # manually assign "list" index
   .....:     df = df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
   .....:     
In [103]: df = df.reset_index()

In [104]: df.set_index(['list', 'index'])
Out[104]: 
                     date_time      name value
list index                                    
1    0     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Tom   129
     1     2015-05-22 05:37:59      Kate     0
     2     2015-05-22 05:37:59  GroupeId     0
2    3     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Tom   129
     4     2015-05-22 05:37:59      Kate     0
     5     2015-05-22 05:37:59  GroupeId     0
```

Comment: thanks, @Anzel, but actually I have a list of lists, so this is my problem, and that's why I want to use Multiindex! I updated discription by adding the desired output

Comment: @fuzzzy_09, as requested, answer updated, you only require to enumerate the lists in data array, give it an index, and add it to each dataframe to append to df. Probably not the most efficient way (using append), but will get your job done.

Comment: thank you very much! it's exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: @fuzzzy_09, not a problem and I'm glad it helps :)

Comment: if you understand well this topic, maybe you could have a look on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174178/pandas-pivot-table-inside-multilevel-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, let `d` be an extract of your array:

```
d = [[{'date_time': '2015-05-22 05:37:59',
   'name': 'Tom',
   'value': '129'},
  {'date_time': '2015-05-22 05:37:59',
   'name': 'Kate',
   'value': '0'}]]
```

I would extract the dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d[0])
```

which returns:

```
             date_time  name value
0  2015-05-22 05:37:59   Tom   129
1  2015-05-22 05:37:59  Kate     0
```

Hope that helps.