# pandas: pivot table inside multilevel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to pivot table, in order to transform some rows values in columns, so from this dataframe `df_behave`

```
list 
                   date_time      field      value
 1    0 2015-05-22 05:37:59      StudentID   129
      1 2015-05-22 05:37:59      SchoolId    3
      2 2015-05-22 05:37:59      GroupeId     45
 2    3 2015-05-26 05:56:59      StudentID   129
      4 2015-05-26 05:56:59      SchoolId     65
      5 2015-05-26 05:56:59      GroupeId    13
      6 2015-05-26 05:56:59      Reference     87
 3    ......................    ......  ......
```

in order to achieve :

```
list 
                      date_time     StudentID   SchoolId  GroupId    Reference
     1       2015-05-22 05:37:59      129           3         45

     2      2015-05-26 05:56:59      129            65        15       87   

     3    ......................    ......  ......
```

with following code:

```
def calculate():
    df_behave['value'] = df_behave['value'].astype(int)
    pi_df=pd.pivot_table(df_behave, 'value', index=['date_time'], columns='field')
    return pi_df
```

and I tried this one:

```
def calculate():
    df_behave['value'] = df_behave['value'].astype(int)
    for liste, new_df in df_behave.groupby(level=0):
        pi_df=pd.pivot_table(new_df, 'value', index=['date_time'], columns='field')
        print pi_df
    return pi_df
```

but the both returned me `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'True'`

Comment: @Alexander is right, for MultiIndex, you'd better reset_index and set for the fields he mentioned and perform an unstack. Perhaps you should filter out the unnecessary fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting your index, setting it to `list`, `date_time` and `field`, and then unstacking `field`.

```
df.reset_index().set_index(['list', 'date_time', 'field']).unstack('field')
```

As your `value` column appears to contain non-numeric data, and from your examples above it should only contain integers, try the following to locate your bad data:

```
bad_rows = []
for n in range(len(df) - 1):
    if not isinstance(df.loc[n, 'value'], int):
        bad_rows.append(n)
```

You may first want to try coercing the values:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype('int')
```

Comment: I checked , there is no 'True' not in value, neither in field!

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 10191 entries, (1.0, 0) to (2392.0, 12584)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
date     10191 non-null object
field    10191 non-null object
value    10191 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 395.8+ KB

Comment: Your `value` column is an object type, which means it contains non-numeric data such as strings.

Comment: I think the problem in this ligne  ```df_behave['value'] = df_behave['value'].astype(int)```, cause just before this assignment I have the error ```DataError: No numeric types to aggregate```, and after assignment  ```ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'True'```, it's quite strange

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander is right, for MultiIndex, you'd better reset_index and set for the fields he mentioned and perform an unstack. Perhaps you should filter out the unnecessary fields?

just some random sample data:

```
In [308]: df
Out[308]: 
                     date_time     field  value
list index                                     
1    0     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Tom      1
     1     2015-05-22 05:37:59      Kate      2
     2     2015-05-22 05:37:59  GroupeId      3
2    3     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Tom      4
     4     2015-05-22 05:37:59      Kate      5
     5     2015-05-22 05:37:59  GroupeId      6

In [310]: df.set_index(['date_time', 'field'], append=True)\
            .reset_index('index')['value']\
            .unstack('field')
Out[310]: 
field                     GroupeId  Kate  Tom
list date_time                               
1    2015-05-22 05:37:59         3     2    1
2    2015-05-22 05:37:59         6     5    4
```