# Pandas Unhashable type : 'list' when using describe()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that has another dictionary as its value and that another dictionary has a list as its value.
For example,

```
{'A' : {'a' : ['1', '2', '3'], 'b' : ['4', '5'], 'c' : ['6']},  
'B' : {'a' : ['7'], 'b' : ['8', '9']}}
```

I want to make a Pandas DataFrame which has `A`, `B` as indices, `a`, `b`, `c` as columns.

What I did is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index')  
df.describe()
```

But I got an error saying:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-88dc07bc979e> in <module>()
      6 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index')  
----> 7 df.describe() # print df  

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in  
 describe(self, percentiles, include, exclude)  
   6825             data = self.select_dtypes(include=include, exclude=exclude)  
   6826   
-> 6827         ldesc = [describe_1d(s) for _, s in data.iteritems()]  
   6828         # set a convenient order for rows  
   6829         names = []  

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in <listcomp>(.0)  
   6825             data = self.select_dtypes(include=include, exclude=exclude)
   6826 
-> 6827         ldesc = [describe_1d(s) for _, s in data.iteritems()]
   6828         # set a convenient order for rows
   6829         names = []

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in describe_1d(data)
   6808                 return describe_numeric_1d(data)
   6809             else:
-> 6810                 return describe_categorical_1d(data)
   6811 
   6812         if self.ndim == 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in describe_categorical_1d(data)
   6782         def describe_categorical_1d(data):
   6783             names = ['count', 'unique']
-> 6784             objcounts = data.value_counts()
   6785             count_unique = len(objcounts[objcounts != 0])
   6786             result = [data.count(), count_unique]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in value_counts(self, normalize, sort, ascending, bins, dropna)
    869         from pandas.core.algorithms import value_counts
    870         result = value_counts(self, sort=sort, ascending=ascending,
--> 871                               normalize=normalize, bins=bins, dropna=dropna)
    872         return result
    873 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in value_counts(values, sort, ascending, normalize, bins, dropna)
    550 
    551         else:
--> 552             keys, counts = _value_counts_arraylike(values, dropna)
    553 
    554             if not isinstance(keys, Index):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in _value_counts_arraylike(values, dropna)
    595         # TODO: handle uint8
    596         f = getattr(htable, "value_count_{dtype}".format(dtype=ndtype))
--> 597         keys, counts = f(values, dropna)
    598 
    599         mask = isna(values)

pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I fix it?

I want result like

```
    a           b       c
A   1   2   3   4   5   6
B   7           8   9
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50350404/edit) to include **what you expect** from the output?

Answer (score 4):

The values will be list objects.  Because of this, you can simply use the `DataFrame` constructor and transpose.  The reason why I mention the list objects is because I'd typically avoid constructing and transposing as that can mess with dtypes.  But in this case, dtyes will be objects anyway.

```
d = {
    'A' : {'a' : ['1', '2', '3'], 'b' : ['4', '5'], 'c' : ['6']},
    'B' : {'a' : ['7'], 'b' : ['8', '9']}
}

pd.DataFrame(d).T

           a       b    c
A  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5]  [6]
B        [7]  [8, 9]  NaN
```

---

However, the problem is with attempting to describe the lists.  What is the point?  I'd guess you want to describe the numbers in the list.  If that's true, I'd construct like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    i: {(j, k): v for j, x in d_.items() for k, v in enumerate(x)}
    for i, d_ in d.items()
}, orient='index')

df

   a            b       c
   0    1    2  0  1    0
A  1    2    3  4  5    6
B  7  NaN  NaN  8  9  NaN
```

Which you can then describe

```
df.describe()

        a        b     c
        0  1  2  0  1  0
count   2  1  1  2  2  1
unique  2  1  1  2  2  1
top     1  2  3  8  5  6
freq    1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Or you can stack the resulting second level of the columns attribute.

```
df.stack().describe()


        a  b  c
count   4  4  1
unique  4  4  1
top     1  8  6
freq    1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the error says about hashability I would first change the inner lists to tuple:

```
d = {'A' : {'a' : ['1', '2', '3'], 'b' : ['4', '5'], 'c' : ['6']},
'B' : {'a' : ['7'], 'b' : ['8', '9']}}

flat = [(k, v.items()) for k,v in d.items()]
d2 = dict()
for k, kv2 in flat:
    dd_pairs = []
    for k2, v2 in kv2:
        dd_pairs.append( (k2,tuple(v2)) )
    d2[k] = dict(dd_pairs)
```

This should unblock you...

Very similar issue was described here: [Pandas Multiindex from array => TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169701/pandas-multiindex-from-array-typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Comment: Can you show how you'd change the inner lists to tuples?

Comment: Change square brackets to round ones

Comment: Assume the input is as described.  It would be more useful if you could show how to convert that input into something you've described.  What you've stated so far is only a clue and isn't complete.

Comment: Code for conversion of inner lists to tuples added.